# Declaring a variable doesnt work unless it equals 0

Tags: javascript

Hey so I have this bit of code. my issue is that it doesnt work unless I set sumNum to an integer and I dont understand why.

```
var sumNum; //var sumNum = 0;

const sumAll = function(startNum, endNum) {
    for(var i = startNum; i<= endNum; i++) {
        sumNum += i;
    }
    return sumNum;
}
```

Comment: If you don't declare the variable as zero you are adding something to `undefined` which results in not-a-number.

Comment: Why use a global variable? Use `let sumNum = 0` inside of the function before the loop -- although for this particular case, why not skip the loop entirely and use known mathematical formulas for the sum of all integers in a given range?

Comment: The exercise I'm doing wants me to use a loop. I declared my variable outside of the loop because it i didnt think i'd be able to return it once i had finished the loop

Answer (score 3):

If you don't define than it is assigned a value [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) implicitly.

and math operation on that will result in [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

```js
console.log(undefined+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happens when it's not a number. The first statement it appears in is `sumNum += i`. When you don't set it to a number it's value is `undefined`, so it calculates `sumNum = undefined + i` which results in `NaN`. And after that it's `sumNum = NaN + i`, which still results in `NaN`.

To fix it you could check the value before and set it to `0` if it's undefined: `sumNum = sumNum || 0` (sets it to 0 when falsy).

But I think you don't even want it to be a global variable, in which case you just need to declare it inside your function (which is better to be declared using the normal syntax)

```js
function sumAll(startNum, endNum) {
  var sumNum = 0;
  for (var i = startNum; i <= endNum; i++) {
    sumNum += i;
  }
  return sumNum;
}

console.log(sumAll(1, 3));
```

Comment: cheers for the input but i dont think that was what was going on here